# How the communities like facebook,orkut can able to track down our mail contact list

Tags: php

How few social communities can able to track down the contact lists from our mail id alone.Is there any MOU or its open for all.

Can anyone explain this.

Thanks
Lokesh.

Answer (score 0):

This question deals with Facebook and GMX specifically: [Importing Facebook friends with API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517096/5517220#5517220)

They shouldn't be able to track down contact information with the E-Mail address alone, though. All the services I know ask you for your user name and password to log in to the actual service.

If you're seeing contact suggestions without giving the network your E-Mail credentials, what probably happens is that they cross-reference your address against other people's contact lists.

Comment: On further analysis i found that Google is providing the portable API to get the contact lists. http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/contacts/docs/poco/1.0/developers_guide.html#Authenticating

Comment: @Lokesh yeah, but that seems to be for Google Contacts only. I think every social network and E-Mail provider is brewing their own in that field

Comment: Is there any possible way to get the list of contacts from any mail servers that user has provided.

Comment: @Lokesh no. It would be a major security flaw.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong they also require password for authenticate and after they accessing their CSV contact file or some other format that has been provided by the Application